# Retrofit 2 send mail via MS graph api returns The value of the parameter 'Message' is empty

Tags: java, spring, retrofit2, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I have a Java Spring project which uses Retrofit 2 to make API calls to the Graph API from Microsoft. I am able to authenticate, read mail boxes and retrieve/read emails. However i am struggling with sending mails.

I have the following code for sending an email:

**Permissions:** Contains the Mail.send

```
    private String[] scopes = [
            "openid",
            "email",
            "profile",
            "User.Read",
            "Mail.Read",
            "Mail.Send",
            "Mail.ReadWrite",
            "Calendars.Read",
            "Calendars.ReadWrite",
            "Contacts.Read",
            "Contacts.ReadWrite",
            "offline_access"
    ];
```

**Retrofit Call:**

```
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST("/v1.0/me/sendMail")
    Call<Message> sendMessage(
            @Body String messageObject
    );
```

**The String that is sent is a JSONString:**

```
"{\"Message\":{\"toRecipients\":[{\"address\":\"test@test.be\",\"name\":\"test@test.be\"}],\"Body\":{\"ContentType\":\"text/html\",\"Content\":\"value(Email_body)=%3Cp%3Etesttext%3C%2Fp%3E\"},\"Subject\":\"testsubject\"},\"SaveToSentItems\":\"true\"}"
```

**HTTP Response:**

```
 <-- 400 Bad Request https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/sendMail (101ms)
 Cache-Control: private
 Transfer-Encoding: chunked
 Content-Type: application/json
 request-id: 94d19c39-4b84-4ee9-98d2-d42d36886e40
 client-request-id: 0c9d2c63-28bf-49c4-9ad6-08d81c6fd4b0
 x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"West Europe","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"5","ScaleUnit":"003","RoleInstance":"AGSFE_IN_27"}}
 Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
 Date: Wed, 09 Oct 2019 07:41:54 GMT

 {
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorInvalidParameter",
    "message": "The value of the parameter 'Message' is empty.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "94d19c39-4b84-4ee9-98d2-d42d36886e40",
      "date": "2019-10-09T07:41:54"
    }
  }
}
<-- END HTTP (253-byte body)
```

Any idea what is causing the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i figured it out, the correct way to post raw json with retrofit 2 is:

```
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST("/v1.0/me/sendMail")
    Call<Message> sendMessage(
            @Body HashMap<String, Object> messageObject
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you should not be having the escaping characters for the double quotes when the json data is *actually* being sent out.

Therefore the string sent out should be unescaped and look something like this.

```
{"Message":{"toRecipients":[{"address":"test@test.be","name":"test@test.be"}],"Body":{"ContentType":"text/html","Content":"value(Email_body)=%3Cp%3Etesttext%3C%2Fp%3E"},"Subject":"testsubject"},"SaveToSentItems":"true"}
```

Furthermore, you will discover that

- `address` is not a valid property for `toRecipients`and you should be inside an `emailAddress` property
- `name` property is invalid and should be removed.
- `ContentType` values can be `text` or `html`

Therefore, the json sent out should look something like this.

```
{
  "Message": {
    "toRecipients": [
      {
        "emailAddress": {
            address:"test@test.be"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Body": {
      "ContentType": "html",
      "Content": "value(Email_body)=%3Cp%3Etesttext%3C%2Fp%3E"
    },
    "Subject": "testsubject"
  },
  "SaveToSentItems": "true"
}
```

You can also read more about the sendMail api at the following link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: I have tried the example in the MS link and it returns the same error. Maybe it is the retrofit call that is wrong.

Comment: Do you construct the json string object with a library like Gson? Or do you do you simply pass a string as a parameter to the retrofit call?

Comment: I built the json with gson but it seems like retrofit2 needs a ```HashMap<String, Object>``` to post it as ure json

Comment: Happy to hear you sorted it out. :)